# Flex 4 binding to mx:Image

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, data-binding

Is it possible to bind a property (don't know which) of the mx:Image control, so that it is (should be) possible to get in form of a bytearray? (using Flex 4)

The reason i'm asking is this: i have to forward the bytearray to a WCF service to be stored and afterwards retrieved!

If this is not directly achievable is there a work-around ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you load content into your image then when the **`Event.COMPLETE`** dispatches (on the image instance) the **`<imageInstance>.content.loaderInfo.bytes`** ByteArray holds the loaded data.

Comment: +1 for this answer.  Although, I'm confused by the Original Poster's request to use binding to get the byteArray.

Comment: thanks very much. so it seems there is no way of directly binding, one must use events too!  @Flextras.com: the reason is this: i want to access my data in a unique way:either declarated (through tags) or programmatically. Apparently this is not viable!

Answer (score 0):

you can use BindingUtils.bindproperty to bind your object to the value of Image.source, like its described [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/binding/utils/BindingUtils.html#bindProperty%28%29) in the docs